# can get value of the input with curl_setopt

Tags: php, curl

**this my file .php**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://mywebsite.com/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$c = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $c;
```

I have form with input type text and with button  i want to ask what if i can get send the input with to my website  with this script ?

Comment: What are you asking for? returning $C will give you the response from the test.php, html and all. or what ever it is you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form on your website has a text input and you want to submit the form to your site using cURL, you're looking for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

In addition to what you have, add:

```
$fields = array(
    'name' => 'Name', // array key corresponds to the name of a field on your form
    'email' => 'you@yoursite.com',
);

$data = http_build_query($fields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$c = curl_exec($ch); // post form to your site
```